# Home-brew Python3 not recognized

Tags: python, installation

I'm trying to get python 3 installed on a reinstall of Catalina on my Mac but everything I've tried is failing.

I've installed Xcode.
I've installed homebrew; I've installed python 3.7 per home-brew and I've tried unlinking && linking but that isn't working. I've added export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH to my PATH and nothing is working. I don't know what I don't know and I don't know what else do to to get python --version to show python 3.

Comment: also I've installed pyenv and tried pyenv global 3.7.6 but it says it's not installed.

Comment: what about python3 --version? do you get anything from that?

Comment: first find where is python3 installed and test `/full/path/to/python --version`

Comment: yes python3 --version shows 3.7.6. Do I need to run $python3 if I have a lib that requires 3?

Comment: I'm not sure what the full path to python3 from homebrew is. all I have is /usr/local/lib/python3.7 but when I type that in terminal it says that directory doesn't exist

Comment: now terminal is saying python is not a recognized command.

Comment: Do you know that `python` and `python3` are different commands?

Comment: Yes, run $python3 if it requires python3.

Comment: No. I was not aware that python3 and python were different. I’ve reset my MacBook and then had to install Catalina. I read that Catalina installed 3 by default but that was not what happened on my machine.